# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: binder0" error while running scala in MAC

Tags: java, macos, scala

I installed scala in my macbook but when I launch it from terminal, I get the below error:

---

```
**scala> error: error while loading Consumer, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/function/Consumer.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 15)
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
<script>:1: error: type InterpreterSettings is not a member of package scala.tools.nsc
object binder0{ var value: scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterSettings = _;  def set(x: Any) = value=x.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterSettings]; }
                                           ^
<script>:1: error: type InterpreterSettings is not a member of package scala.tools.nsc
object binder0{ var value: scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterSettings = _;  def set(x: Any) = value=x.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterSettings]; }
                                                                                                                            ^
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: binder0**
```

---

Is it something regarding java_home setup ?
Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could be down to the fact that Java 8 is only "experimentally" supported at the moment, see here:

http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1